# Connect to external mysql server from a specific ip

Tags: php, mysql

I've been searching and couldn't find an answer to this.

I have a server that holds multiple ip addresses - lets say 1.1.1.1 (as the main ip) and 1.1.1.2
I need to connect to an external mysql server that allows only 1.1.1.2 to connect to it but it tries to connect from 1.1.1.1

is there any way to "choose" what ip the server will try to connect from?

thanks

Comment: i think it depends on which ip-address your webserver is running.

Comment: I tried to connect with PDO from 1.1.1.2/test.php

Comment: what is the OS that holds multiple ip addresses?

Comment: I suspect the only way to deal with this would be to configure your network routing table so that all requests to the IP of the MySQL server go out over the .2 interface. How you do that will depend on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

1) try check my.cnf (for bind to multiple IPs)

```
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
#skip-networking
```

2) check server firewall rules (or try disable firewall to test connection).

More information:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-mysqld-server-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address/
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: The question is about a *client* with multiple IP addresses, not the server.